# Сбой при установке IDE Python

Tags: python, отладка

Всем привет! Ситуация такая: слетела windows 8.1 и была автоматически восстановлена, но в ходе восстановления были удалены многие приложения, в т.ч. "стоковая" IDE Python. При попытке установки выдаёт ошибку 0x80070643 - в процессе установки произошла неисправимая ошибка, подробности в лог-файле. Лог-файл, к сожалению, полностью в текст вопроса прикрепить не могу, но мне кажется, ошибка где-то здесь, в конце:

```
[1788:0FCC][2022-11-11T13:09:13]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[1788:0FCC][2022-11-11T13:09:13]i300: Apply begin
[1788:0FCC][2022-11-11T13:09:13]i010: Launching elevated engine process.
[1788:0FCC][2022-11-11T13:09:14]i011: Launched elevated engine process.
[1788:0FCC][2022-11-11T13:09:15]i012: Connected to elevated engine.
[0564:0F44][2022-11-11T13:09:15]i358: Pausing automatic updates.
[0564:0F44][2022-11-11T13:09:15]i359: Paused automatic updates.
[0564:0F44][2022-11-11T13:09:15]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[0564:0F44][2022-11-11T13:09:15]i361: Created a system restore point.
[1788:0FCC][2022-11-11T13:09:15]i370: Session begin, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{7f8381ad-2e42-4432-8de5-c7beebe1009f}, options: 0x7, disable resume: No
[1788:0FCC][2022-11-11T13:09:15]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\3C5C~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{89A1F3A8-EA2D-4DA6-BDFE-77B7217BBA7F}\.be\python-3.11.0-amd64.exe' to: 'C:\Users\Вова\AppData\Local\Package Cache\{7f8381ad-2e42-4432-8de5-c7beebe1009f}\python-3.11.0-amd64.exe'
[1788:0FCC][2022-11-11T13:09:15]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: CPython-3.11, version: 3.11.150.0
[1788:0FCC][2022-11-11T13:09:15]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{7f8381ad-2e42-4432-8de5-c7beebe1009f}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[1788:1720][2022-11-11T13:09:15]w343: Prompt for source of package: ucrt_JustForMe, payload: ucrt_JustForMe, path: C:\Users\Вова\Downloads\ucrt.msi
[1788:1720][2022-11-11T13:09:15]i338: Acquiring package: ucrt_JustForMe, payload: ucrt_JustForMe, download from: https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.0/amd64/ucrt.msi
[1788:1720][2022-11-11T13:09:15]i305: Verified acquired payload: ucrt_JustForMe at path: C:\Users\Вова\AppData\Local\Package Cache\.unverified\ucrt_JustForMe, moving to: C:\Users\Вова\AppData\Local\Package Cache\{D743B419-E316-4F11-BBAC-EB302B434207}v3.11.150.0\ucrt.msi.
[1788:0FCC][2022-11-11T13:09:15]i323: Registering package dependency provider: {D743B419-E316-4F11-BBAC-EB302B434207}, version: 3.11.150.0, package: ucrt_JustForMe
[1788:0FCC][2022-11-11T13:09:15]i301: Applying execute package: ucrt_JustForMe, action: Install, path: C:\Users\Вова\AppData\Local\Package Cache\{D743B419-E316-4F11-BBAC-EB302B434207}v3.11.150.0\ucrt.msi, arguments: ' ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" MSIFASTINSTALL="7" TARGETDIR="C:\Users\Вова\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311"'
[1788:1720][2022-11-11T13:09:15]i304: Verified existing payload: core_JustForMe at path: C:\Users\Вова\AppData\Local\Package Cache\{1ED03561-12AC-4A6A-AA85-583281BF0121}v3.11.150.0\core.msi.
[1788:1720][2022-11-11T13:09:15]i304: Verified existing payload: exe_JustForMe at path: C:\Users\Вова\AppData\Local\Package Cache\{B28E4BED-428C-40CB-9A29-41E46263246D}v3.11.150.0\exe.msi.
[1788:1720][2022-11-11T13:09:15]i304: Verified existing payload: dev_JustForMe at path: C:\Users\Вова\AppData\Local\Package Cache\{74A2D2BF-BD4F-4D82-812F-EDEB21EA443F}v3.11.150.0\dev.msi.
[1788:1720][2022-11-11T13:09:15]i304: Verified existing payload: lib_JustForMe at path: C:\Users\Вова\AppData\Local\Package Cache\{CB7E1801-9FB8-4763-A369-1D7F290AB24D}v3.11.150.0\lib.msi.
[1788:1720][2022-11-11T13:09:15]i304: Verified existing payload: test_JustForMe at path: C:\Users\Вова\AppData\Local\Package Cache\{D4A2E83A-3BD5-4E0D-9577-7F8CA74B876B}v3.11.150.0\test.msi.
[1788:1720][2022-11-11T13:09:15]i304: Verified existing payload: doc_JustForMe at path: C:\Users\Вова\AppData\Local\Package Cache\{D3773C88-43C6-46CD-AE5F-627FF6C6E5D4}v3.11.150.0\doc.msi.
[1788:1720][2022-11-11T13:09:15]i304: Verified existing payload: tools_JustForMe at path: C:\Users\Вова\AppData\Local\Package Cache\{BD29D023-6B95-47FE-B480-598840EB9A28}v3.11.150.0\tools.msi.
[1788:1720][2022-11-11T13:09:15]i304: Verified existing payload: tcltk_JustForMe at path: C:\Users\Вова\AppData\Local\Package Cache\{6FBFD1F4-0412-4DBB-AA00-F71278CAB664}v3.11.150.0\tcltk.msi.
[0564:17DC][2022-11-11T13:09:15]i304: Verified existing payload: launcher_AllUsers at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{0E6EEAC9-4913-4C2F-B7D2-761B27C35D7C}v3.11.7966.0\launcher.msi.
[1788:1720][2022-11-11T13:09:15]i304: Verified existing payload: pip_JustForMe at path: C:\Users\Вова\AppData\Local\Package Cache\{0D8459AB-4636-4CD5-A41B-569D7CE159B8}v3.11.150.0\pip.msi.
[1788:1720][2022-11-11T13:09:15]i304: Verified existing payload: path_JustForMe at path: C:\Users\Вова\AppData\Local\Package Cache\{ACF8763C-83E8-4BE1-B67C-DF86C2E1240A}v3.11.150.0\path.msi.
[1788:0FCC][2022-11-11T13:09:15]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.
[1788:0FCC][2022-11-11T13:09:15]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-user MSI package.
[1788:0FCC][2022-11-11T13:09:15]i319: Applied execute package: ucrt_JustForMe, result: 0x80070643, restart: None
[1788:0FCC][2022-11-11T13:09:15]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[1788:0FCC][2022-11-11T13:09:15]i318: Skipped rollback of package: ucrt_JustForMe, action: Uninstall, already: Absent
[1788:0FCC][2022-11-11T13:09:15]i319: Applied rollback package: ucrt_JustForMe, result: 0x0, restart: None
[1788:0FCC][2022-11-11T13:09:15]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {D743B419-E316-4F11-BBAC-EB302B434207}, package: ucrt_JustForMe
[1788:0FCC][2022-11-11T13:09:15]i351: Removing cached package: ucrt_JustForMe, from path: C:\Users\Вова\AppData\Local\Package Cache\{D743B419-E316-4F11-BBAC-EB302B434207}v3.11.150.0\
[1788:0FCC][2022-11-11T13:09:15]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{7f8381ad-2e42-4432-8de5-c7beebe1009f}, resume: None, restart: None, disable resume: No
[1788:0FCC][2022-11-11T13:09:15]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: CPython-3.11
[1788:0FCC][2022-11-11T13:09:15]i352: Removing cached bundle: {7f8381ad-2e42-4432-8de5-c7beebe1009f}, from path: C:\Users\Вова\AppData\Local\Package Cache\{7f8381ad-2e42-4432-8de5-c7beebe1009f}\
[1788:0FCC][2022-11-11T13:09:15]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{7f8381ad-2e42-4432-8de5-c7beebe1009f}, resume: None, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[1788:0FCC][2022-11-11T13:09:16]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80070643, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

Подскажите, как можно решить данный сбой?

Comment: Что такое "стоковая" IDE Python?

Comment: IDE с сайта https://www.python.org/

Comment: Там нет IDE. Если вы про IDLE - это далеко не IDE, это довольно простой редактор + интерактивная среда (REPL).

Comment: Ценное уточнение, но пока оно мне не помогает.

Comment: Если нужен ценный совет - переустанавливайте систему полностью, вряд ли проблемами с установкой Python ваши проблемы закончатся.

Comment: Насколько я помню, питон не любит русские буквы в путях. Попробуйте установить в каталог, где в пути только английские буквы. Ну то есть без вот этого `Вова`. Хотя устанавливать в каталог пользователя в принципе может быть правильно, но...

Comment: Дело в том, что я пытаюсь устанавливать его туда же, где он был раньше. Т.е. он явно может там работать. Нашёл информацию, что ему могут мешать какие-то старые файлы от прошлого Python-a или данные в кэше, но пока не могу найти их все. Возможно, просто систему переустановлю - такой баг и ошибка не только с Python повторяются

Comment: А может надо от администратора ставить? Хотя если в каталог пользователя, то не должно быть так, но мало ли.